# Is "IsPointerOverGameObject" Deprecated in Unity 2019.2+?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to detect if my cursor is over a UI element in the scene (not in the editor). In past versions, I could just use `EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject()`, but it seems that `EventSystems` no longer exists as a part of `UnityEngine`.

Looking at the [documenation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.html) for 2019.2, UnityEngine.EventSystems is not there, but in [2019.1](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.html) it is. The [release notes](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2019.2.0) make no mention of this that i can see. Just gone.

So, how am I to detect when a cursor is over a UI element?

Comment: It is in the package [`Unity UI`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/EventSystem.html) via the Package Manager now

Answer (score 2):

Alright, this was unrelated to the documentation. EventSystem clearly still exists because it exists in my scene. Another cursory look revealed that my IDE was giving me trouble which lead to errors in the debugger.

The best way to get at this is still `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()`, and make sure you are `using UnityEngine.EventSystems`.

However, the documentation is STILL missing it.

Comment: The documentation is not missing it just got moved to a separate package. https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.html and ofc as alwqys Unity is not on top of communications...

Comment: Are you sure? I can't find any information about `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()` in that documentation.

Comment: I found it from that link (and I too was initially confused because this was unceremoniously removed from the main documentation)  https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.html#UnityEngine_EventSystems_EventSystem_IsPointerOverGameObject